# Batch operations for ant-design/table

Tags: reactjs, antd

In ant-design design documentation they show that when one or more elements are selected from a table, a toolbar can appear and overlay the table head. I'm not finding anything on how to implement it in the developers components documentation.
Follow this link to open the docs page: https://ant.design/docs/spec/data-list#batch-operations

[image showing the feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qn21e.png)

Any idea on how to implement it ?

Thanks

Comment: Consider using Protable (https://pro-components.antdigital.dev/en-US/components/table). Check out this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/nq5dkz

Comment: @Shade thank you. I already checked the pro-components, but when an elements is selected the header appears with the info about the selection, and the header is positioned above the table-head. So it's not covering my use case ...

Comment: All right @Shade. Thank you. I'll probably implement the toolbar by myself in styling it as it appears where I want. I was hoping that the table could handle it by itself assuming that they are showing it in an example ... Thank you again!

Comment: Well, I don't think the Table component alone can do what you want. You need to create the toolbar and the corresponding actions on your own. Check out this example: codesandbox.io/s/98fsjp?file=/demo.tsx You can render different things on your toolbar depends on if something is selected.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.